# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, osgi, aws-sdk

Using this bundle - aws-java-sdk-osgi-1.11.26.jar in OSGI Server

Below Error is thrown when this is executed `AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client( credentials );`

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration
        at com.amazonaws.ClientConfigurationFactory.getDefaultConfig(ClientConfigurationFactory.java:46)
        at com.amazonaws.ClientConfigurationFactory.getConfig(ClientConfigurationFactory.java:36)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:440)
```

Any solution to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all suggestions

The ClientConfiguration of 
aws-java-sdk-osgi-1.11.26.jar is dependent of Jackson-databind.jar 
Jackson-databind.jar is dependent on Jackson-core.jar
So it is not able to initialize ClientConfiguration.

Added Import-Package importing all from jackson-core-osgi.jar in Manifest of Jackson-databind-osgi.jar

Then the issue is resolved

Note: All dependent jars are converted to OSGI jars and deployed

Comment: How did you achieved that? I want to do similar thing with gradle.

Answer (score 1):

Well, make sure that aws-java-sdk-osgi-1.11.26.jar is present on your classpath, because the class itself is present in the jar.
I've just downloaded the jar.

[image: aws-java-sdk-osgi-1.11.26.jar]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing an Import-Package statement in your bundle Manifest. Not sure how you build your bundle but I would recommend to use bnd in some form for it. For example I typically use the maven-bundle-plugin which uses bnd under the hood. Bnd is able to figure out the imports automatically for most cases.

Comment: <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
     <obrRepository>NONE</obrRepository>
     <instructions>
      ...
      <Import-Package>
       com.amazonaws.*;
       javax.ws.rs.*,
       org.apache.http.entity,
       
      </Import-Package>
      <Service-Component>*</Service-Component>
     </instructions>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>

Comment: Can you try to remove the Import-Package statement. In most casses the default should do the right thing. Your setting will override the default of picking up all necessary packages .. maybe one is missing. On the other hand at least the import for com.amazonaws should be present with your config.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, restarting the flink cluster solved the problem.