# how to read file from s3 in scala AWS glue job without using spark?

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, apache-spark, etl, aws-glue

i am trying to read a csv from my s3 bucket as a BufferReader class object. I found the solution from internet which says :-
Certainly! Here's an example of how you can read a file from Amazon S3 in an AWS Glue job using Scala without using Spark:

1. Import the necessary libraries:

```scala
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest
import scala.io.Source
```

2. Create an S3 client:

```scala
val s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient()
```

3. Specify the S3 bucket and file path:

```scala
val bucketName = "your_bucket_name"
val fileKey = "path/to/your/file.txt"
```

4. Use the S3 client to download the file from S3 and read its content:

```scala
val s3Object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, fileKey))
val inputStream = s3Object.getObjectContent
val fileContent = Source.fromInputStream(inputStream).mkString
```

In the code above, replace `"your_bucket_name"` with the name of your S3 bucket and `"path/to/your/file.txt"` with the actual path to your file in S3.

The `getObject()` method retrieves the file object from S3, and `getObjectContent()` returns an input stream for reading the object's data. The `Source.fromInputStream()` function is used to read the content from the input stream and convert it into a string.

You can then process the `fileContent` as needed within your Glue job. Make sure to handle any exceptions and error cases that may occur when interacting with S3.

But unfortunately it is not working it throws an error which says :-

```
ERROR [main] glue.ProcessLauncher (Logging.scala:logError(98)): Exception in User Class
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.JESSchedulerBackend.<init>(JESClusterManager.scala:212) ~[AWSGlueSparkResourceManager-1.0.jar:3.3.0-amzn-1]
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.JESClusterManager.createSchedulerBackend(JESClusterManager.scala:74) ~[AWSGlueSparkResourceManager-1.0.jar:3.3.0-amzn-1]
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$createTaskScheduler(SparkContext.scala:2990) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.3.0-amzn-1.jar:3.3.0-amzn-1]
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:564) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.3.0-amzn-1.jar:3.3.0-amzn-1]
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:130) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.3.0-amzn-1.jar:3.3.0-amzn-1]
    at GlueApp$.main(metanome_algo_test.scala:31) ~[metanome_algo_test.scala.jar:?]
    at GlueApp.main(metanome_algo_test.scala) ~[metanome_algo_test.scala.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_372]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_372]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_372]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_372]
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.SparkProcessLauncherPlugin.invoke(ProcessLauncher.scala:50) ~[AWSGlueSparkResourceManager-1.0.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.SparkProcessLauncherPlugin.invoke$(ProcessLauncher.scala:50) ~[AWSGlueSparkResourceManager-1.0.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.ProcessLauncher$$anon$1.invoke(ProcessLauncher.scala:92) ~[AWSGlueSparkResourceManager-1.0.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.ProcessLauncher.launch(ProcessLauncher.scala:163) ~[AWSGlueSparkResourceManager-1.0.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.ProcessLauncher$.main(ProcessLauncher.scala:30) ~[AWSGlueSparkResourceManager-1.0.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.ProcessLauncher.main(ProcessLauncher.scala) ~[AWSGlueSparkResourceManager-1.0.jar:?]
```

Can anyone help me in this, please.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: googling `aws Could not initialize class ClientConfiguration` return different posts saying that it could be a dependency issue with jackson. Like [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39641202/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-com-amazonaws-clientc). Not sure if that could be your case